# Magento 1.9 - CCAvenue Orders Automatically Cancelling

Tags: orders, error, magento1.9.2.3, qty

I have received order, if i try to take invoice its not possible to do that because of qty canceled as well as Canceled updated in Comment History,

I am using **CCAvenue Payment Gateway**.

[image]

How to solve the issue?

Comment: Is this an online method (using gateway) or an offline one? Is the a decision manager or a fraud system that can cancel the order? Or Just the cancel action was clicked inententionnally?

Comment: Payment gateway online.

Comment: Can you share the whode order status history?

Comment: Status History = https://snipboard.io/ZHEbjh.jpg

Comment: seems to be very specific case related to your website. do you have an automatic shipping process ? which checks quantities in warehouse for example and have the ability to cancel the order automatically ? are you the only user on admin ? you confirm no one did cancel order from admin panel ?

Comment: Yes, we have 4 admin, i asked them individually they wont did nothing.

Answer (score 2):

I cannot tell you the reason why the order was canceled. There could be a lot of reasons

- payment processor sent a message back for canceling the order
- someone actually canceled it from admin
- ,,,

But I can tell you how to make it invoice-able again.
Take the order id. The `entity_id` field in the `sales_order` table, not the increment id.
Let's say it's 110.

Now run these queries:

```
update sales_flat_order set state = 'processing' where entity_id = 110;
update sales_flat_order_item set qty_canceled = 0.0000 where order_id = 110;
```

Now you should see the invoice button and you should be able to invoice the order.
Please backup your db before doing this in case I'm wrong.

Comment: May i know why payment processor sent a message back for canceling the order?

Comment: I didn't say that happened. I said it could happen. Maybe for insufficient funds, or maybe the customer asked the company to revert the payment, or fraud suspicion, or  anything else.

Comment: fyi - Full amount received, we called them they did nothing.

Comment: for the last time...I'm not saying this is exactly what happened. It could have been one of the ways the order got canceled. But not necessarily. Probably something else did it.

Comment: Upcoming days so many order canceled by automatically. May i know the all reasons about canceled order automatically. Can i get any documentation?  thanks

Comment: For my clarity, there is no table called sales_order if wrong pls correct me. Thank you.

Comment: I thought this was for magento2. In magento 1 is called `sales_flat_order`. I will update the answer